# How to get rid of color bar between cells on iOS table (update footer color)

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

I've created a table and was using the default grey color. I then changed it to a much lighter grey, updating the background color of the table and cells to the lighter grey. Each cell is on a new section, which allows for the space between cells. However, as you can see that dark grey bar is in-between each of the cells. I would like to make it the same color as the background.

I haven't changed any colour in the code. The changes are made via the storyboard. I have updated the background colour to the cell, the view in the cel, the table and the view containing the table. I have set the tint colour too clear.

It's the footer which has the different color, changing the height of the below changes the height of the grey area:

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
         return 30
     }
```

[image: Table with grey bar between cells]

Comment: show your tried code

Comment: I've added almost no code. I could add screenshots of the attributes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe thats the footer of the section, try changing it's color, by using the following tableView datasource method:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplayFooterView view: UIView, forSection section: Int) {
     view.tintColor = .red
}
```

Comment: You are correct it's the footer section. I've changed the height and the height of the area changed. This did not change the color fo the footer though

Comment: @trees_are_great are you using a custom footer view?

Comment: No, only the bit that says the footer height

Comment: @trees_are_great Try setting the tintColor instead, I've updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

The property you are seeking is the UITableView Separator color. i.e.:

```
tableView.separatorColor = UIColor.red
```

[image]

Comment: I've set the separator to none (and given it a clear color) in the attributes inspector. In code, I've tried this and it had no effect.